# Drawing a grid of circles in xcode/swift

Tags: ios, swift, graphics, grid, draw

How would I go abouts getting an effect in a view controller like the wonderful work of art attached in the following link?

[Circles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CN6oA.jpg)
I do have some idea, ranging from actually using ASCII text (I know, super wrong way) to a collection view of pictures, to what I suspect is the "right" way, done with core graphics. But I am asking in case there is a super easy/right methodology I will one day discover and facepalm.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that there are two primary ways for you to draw a grid of circles.

The primary way is to draw them using UIBezierPath or by using a collection view of images of circles.

For simple shapes, it is recommended that you choose the first option simply because your choices of circles aren't restricted by your images.

Here is a link for you to get [started](http://www.raywenderlich.com/90690/modern-core-graphics-with-swift-part-1).